# How to parse this kind of string using php?

Tags: php

Now I am trying to import contact details from a csv file. In csv file phone number or mobile number are added like this format

Eg :- 9947321570/9947321571/9947321572 
                  OR
      9947321570;9947321571;9947321572
                  OR
      9947321570,9947321571,9947321572

How can I parse this kind of data?

Comment: can they appear mixed, e.g. can there be '/' delimited entries and ';' delimited entries in one file? Also, is that just one line or are they terminated with newlines? What is the meaning of the fields on one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not using same set of delimiter, how to expect it will work???

spent some effort to make the csv to use same set of delimiter,

example, to use `str_replace` to replace the uncommon delimiter to `,`

```
str_replace(array(';','/'), ',', $field_for_phone_number);
```